# Maven warnings during javafx sources compilation

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm writing a JavaFX standalone application on Apache NetBeans 12.3 with JDK 17.
Now, when I run my app I get issues like the ones thst follow:

```
 Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.ingv:pickfx:jar:0.0.0-develop-SNAPSHOT
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.6.3:super-pom, jar:file:/Applications/NetBeans/Apache%20NetBeans%2012.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/java/maven/lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.3.jar!/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml, line 113, column 19
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.6.3:super-pom, jar:file:/Applications/NetBeans/Apache%20NetBeans%2012.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/java/maven/lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.3.jar!/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml, line 125, column 19
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing. @ org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.6.3:super-pom, jar:file:/Applications/NetBeans/Apache%20NetBeans%2012.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/java/maven/lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.3.jar!/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml, line 137, column 19

It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

I found that this might be related to plugin  tags, but I still can't find a solution to fix it.
Here follows my pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.ingv</groupId>
    <artifactId>pickfx</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.9</version> 
   
    
    <!-- <url>https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis</url> <url>https://esri.jfrog.io/artifactory/arcgis</url>-->
    <!--<url>https://dl.bintray.com/esri/arcgis/</url>
    <url>https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis</url>
    -->
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>arcgis</id>
            <url>https://esri.jfrog.io/artifactory/arcgis</url>
           <!-- <url>https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis</url> -->
        </repository>  
        
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
            <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo-snapshot</id>
            <name>OSGeo Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
            <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
        
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>  
        <arcgis.version>100.5.0</arcgis.version>    
        <geotools.version>27-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
    
    </properties> 
   
    
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.26</version>
         </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.brouillard.oss/jgitver -->
        <!-- Java GIT semantic versioning -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.brouillard.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgitver</artifactId>
            <version>0.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>fr.brouillard.oss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jgitver-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.studio/org.apache.commons.io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- OPEN JFX -->  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>   
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>    
                
                        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.sociaal</groupId>
            <artifactId>freetts</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>    
        <!--ArcGIS Runtime SDK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esri.arcgisruntime</groupId>
            <artifactId>arcgis-java</artifactId>
            <version>${arcgis.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jniLibs is available in different directory, it does not need to be added in final pickfx jar -->
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esri.arcgisruntime</groupId>
            <artifactId>arcgis-java-resources</artifactId>
            <version>${arcgis.version}</version>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esri.geometry</groupId>
            <artifactId>esri-geometry-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esri.arcgisruntime</groupId>
            <artifactId>arcgis-java-toolkit</artifactId>
            <version>100.2.1</version>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.38.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- SWAGGER   -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.10</version>
          </dependency>     
        <!-- GOOGLE-GSON -->  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>       
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gsonfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson-fire</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-primitives</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-convert</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
            <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>         
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.3</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                 <execution>
                  <goals>
                   <goal>xjc</goal>
                  </goals>
                 </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                 <sources>
                    <!-- <source>src/main/resources/quakeml-2.0/xsd/QuakeML-2.0.xsd</source> --> <!-- QuakeML-BEDT-1.3.xsd</source> -->
                    <source>src/main/resources/quakeml-1.2/xsd/QuakeML-1.2.xsd</source>
                </sources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--ArcGIS Java Maven Plugin-->
            <!--
            <plugin>
              <groupId>com.esri.arcgisruntime</groupId>
              <artifactId>arcgis-java-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.0</version>
            </plugin>  
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                  <archive>
                    <manifest>
                      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                      <mainClass>org.ingv.pickfx.NewMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 
          
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.ingv.pickfx.NewMain</mainClass>
                    <executable>${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                  <mainClass>org.ingv.pickfx.NewMain</mainClass>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.takari</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I added  tags to all the plugins that I use, but it still does not fix the warning.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Is `<version>0.0.</version>` for javafx-maven-plugin really what you had in mind? Shouldn't this be 0.0.8?

Comment: It's 0.0.8, sorry.  But this does not solve the issue